# iTunes style layout using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, itunes

What is the best way (using HTML/CSS) to create an iTunes-style layout with the following features:

- a left column with a fixed width but
  fluid height (scrollbars for
  overflow) (BLUE below)
- a main content column with
  fluid width and height (scrollbars for overflow) (RED below)
- a bottom right
  box with fixed width and height which
  remains stuck to the bottom of the
  browser? (GREEN below)

Here is an example:

[image: iTunes layout example as described above]

I'm happy to use Javascript/JQuery if there really isn't a pure CSS solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, full credit to the [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) guys for the image above. Cappuccino is great, but a little large for this project.

Comment: Have you given an attempt to create this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/RAkKN/show/:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
	<head>
		<title></title>
		<style>
body {
	margin: 0;
	padding: 0;
}
div {
	opacity: 0.5;
}
#red { background: red; }
#green { background: lime; }
#blue { background: blue; }
#green, 
#blue {
	width: 200px;
	position: fixed;
	left: 0;
}
#green {
	bottom: 0;
	height: 200px;
}
#blue {
	bottom: 200px;
	top: 0;
	overflow: auto;
}
#red {
	margin: 0 0 0 200px;
}
span { /* force overflow, for example */
	display: block;
	height: 3000px;
}
		</style>
	</head>
	<body>
		<div id="blue">
			<span></span>
		</div>
		<div id="green"></div>
		<div id="red">
			<span></span>
		</div>
	</body>
</html>
```

This does not support IE6; there are a number of different ways you can go to get the exact same thing or merely similar in IE6 (even without JavaScript), but the least tedious probably *is* just to use [JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at [ExtJs](http://www.extjs.com/) for this.

It will let you do quite sophisticated flexible layouts, and would work well for this kind of app, e.g., [portal example](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/portal/portal.html).

Comment: You don't need JS for this, and certainly not an entire library.

Answer (score -1):

The way I see it...you would want *something* like the following psudeo-css (this won't work IRL, you wouldn't want #left and #right measuring in percent [this should be set with javascript]).

```
html, body{height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
    .clearfix{/****the usual clearfix code****/}
        #left {height:100%;float:left;width:25%;}
            #top{height:75%;overflow:auto;}
            #bottom{height:25%;}
        #right {height:100%;width:75%;float:left;overflow:auto;}
```

You could also use, dare I say it...TABLES!

--

And lastly..you will need to use javascript.